Can anyone explain how this format verb in golang works
In the Golang playground sample "Clear Screen",
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const col = 30
    // Clear the screen by printing \x0c.
    bar := fmt.Sprintf("\x0c[%%-%vs]", col)
    for i := 0; i < col; i++ {
        fmt.Printf(bar, strings.Repeat("=", i)+">")
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    fmt.Printf(bar+" Done!", strings.Repeat("=", col))
}

on line 12 uses this formatting verb syntax, "[%%-%vs]".  Can anyone explain how it's being parsed?  The double "%%" and the "%vs" is not making sense to me.  Thanks.
Tried breaking it into pieces and running with literal substitutions, like for col value, but cannot produce the same result as running the sample produces.

Do some debugging by taking a look at the intermediate string:
// Clear the screen by printing \x0c.
bar := fmt.Sprintf("\x0c[%%-%vs]", col)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", bar)


"\f[%-30s]"

This string is then itself used as a format string, where %-30s indicates that the argument string should be padded by space characters on the right until it’s 30 characters wide.

The verbs are explained in the documentation:
%v  the value in a default format
    when printing structs, the plus flag (%+v) adds field names
...
%%  a literal percent sign; consumes no value

Here's how the format string in the question is translated to the string returned from fmt.Sprintf:

[  -> [
%% -> %
- -> -
%v -> the value in default format.
s -> s
] -> ]


%% makes a percent sign.
%v you probably know about.
s is just the letter s.
So if the thing being formatted is the number 42, the result is the string %-42s. Which happens to be a valid format string on its own, of course.

when you run the sample no '%" or "s" appears in the output.
